# Can anyone explain how to get all the mismatch between two Array of JSON Object responses in karate?

Tags: karate

```json
[
   {
      "Name":"Joseph",
      "City":"Chennai",
      "Address":"Anna street",
      "values":[
         "NA"
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"Sathya",
      "City":"Chennai",
      "Address":"Mugan street",
      "values":[
         "engineering"
      ]
   }
]
```

How to Iterate over array of objects as mentioned above. Like if I have two Array of `JSON` as above and I want to check the mismatch between those.

If it's is a normal Json objects were are able to get the mismatch using scenario outline and iterating through the keys.
In this case it  is a array of objects. So how we can do it. Please help.

Comment: if the linked q & a does not help, please consider this as NOT SUPPORTED. you are welcome to contribute code or look for another framework

Comment: and if you have arrays, please spend some time to understand how to transform and loop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms - if that is not possible, please give up on using karate :)